# Replacing the standard Glyphicons Halflings with Glyphicons PRO in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I've bought the full Glyphicons PRO package and want to use it with Bootstrap 3.

However, I can't seem to find comprehensive documentation on how to do this. The Glyphicons site lacks a "How to use section" and an accompanying PDF isn't much help either - it was mentioning a glyphicons.css file that wasn't part of the download package...

**Any help on how to make this replacement is much appreciated.**

Answer (score 3):

In your bootstrap folder is a fonts folder (mostly in the CSS folder) that contains the Glyphicons fonts.

Those need to be replaced with the pro version you have.

Next you need to point (if the fonts not having the same name) to your new fonts in the bootstrap CSS. This depends on what technology you are using.

But you have to search for:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format("embedded-opentype"), url('fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format("woff"), url('fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format("truetype"), url('fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format("svg");
}
```

and replace the font file names (or maybe location if you are placing them in another place)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your suggestions but can't get it to work. It's seems Glyphicons PRO has another CSS syntax compared to Halflings...

Comment: then you need to replace the original glyphicons font-face with the css provided in the PRO version

Comment: One note, the glyphicons included in the bootstrap css have the class glyphicon glyphicon-something, those in the PRO version have glyphicons glyphicons-something (note the s)

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in some comments above, they are differences in the bootstrap FREE version of Glyphicons compared to the one from the Glyphicons PRO package.

As a recap, here as the main differences:

- [**difference**] :  [*Bootstrap's Glyphicons FREE*] **VS**   [*Glyphicons PRO*]
- **icon font name** : *"glyphicons-halflings-regular"* **VS**  *"glyphicons-regular"*
- **css class names** : *"glyphicon" , "glyphicon-*"* **VS** *"glyphicon**s**"    , "glyphicon**s**-*"*
- **font family**   :  *"Glyphicons Halflings"*   **VS**   *"Glyphicons Regular"*

Given that Bootstrap's Glyphicons is a **subset** of Glypicons PRO, you shouldn't use both, but instead replace the vanilla Bootstrap's ***glyphicons.less*** file (in the Bootstrap "less" folder) by the one from the PRO package.

If you are using js build tools like **Bower** & **Grunt**, you can have the **grunt-contrib-copy** task to automate that for you:

```
copy: {
server: {               
    files: [{//replace the vanilla Bootstrap's FREE glyphicons.less by the PRO's version
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'path/to/your/less', //put glyphicons.less (PRO version) here                  
        dest:'path/to/bower_components/bootstrap/less',
        src: 'glyphicons.less'
    }]
}
```

}

This task can be registered in :

```
 grunt.registerTask('serve', [
    'copy:server', //replace the vanilla bootstrap's glyphicons
     // your other tasks here, for eg: 
     // 'less:server', // to compile the less

    ]);
```

And will run on:

```
grunt serve
```

Comment: There are small differences in contents as well. For example `glyphicon-trash` should be `glyphicons-bin`, `glyphicon-stats` is missing completely, `glyphicon-comment` should be `glyphicon-comments`.  Maybe some more.