# Glyphicon Pro in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use Glyphicons Pro (Social and Filetypes as well). But bootstrap has a different way for icons.

In bootstrap: `glyphicon glyphicon-ok`
In glyphicon: `glyphicon ok`

IMHO the last option is better.

My question is: how can I use glyphicons pro in bootstrap, as the `glyphicon` class is already reserved by halflings.

My ideas:

- remove halflings from bootstrap, and use the one provided by glyphicon
- integrate the pro icons into bootstrap, but the mentioned question needs to be answered first

There are many similar questions on stackoverflow, and they are either about replacing halflings or not properly answered.

Answer (score 2):

You should compile a Bootstrap version without the gylphicons component [here.](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)
Just uncheck Glyphicons under components, then go to the bottom and click "Compile and download".

After that you can include Glyphicons Pro without conflict in class names.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution, but:
* I use grunt and bower, so I don't download anything at all from bootstrap sit.
* I would like to INTEGRATE the Pro package, so BC should not be broken.

Comment: Then you should just remove **glyphicons.less** from the Bootstrap library and from bootstrap.less, then add the css for Glyphicons in a less file and **@import** it in bootstrap.less. This way it will get compiled with Bootstrap.

Comment: _"I would like to INTEGRATE the Pro package, so BC should not be broken."_

Answer (score 0):

The following approach worked for me as of Bootstrap 3.3.6:

1. Download and extract Bootstrap source locally.

   ```
   you@home:~$ mkdir bs3_src && cd bs3_src/
   you@home:~bs3_src/$ git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git .
   ```
2. Extract Glyphicons Pro package and navigate to the "Glyphicons Regular" family `glyphicons.less` file under `(src)/glyphicons_pro/glyphicons/web/html_css/less`. Replace `bootstrap/less/glyphicons.less` with this one. Replace all of the halfling font files with their `glyphicons-regular.*` counterparts from the PRO source into `bootstrap/fonts/`. If you desire the `.social` and `.filetype` fonts, add `glyphicons-filetypes.less` and `glyphicons-social.less`from their respective subfolders into `bootstrap/less/` (don't forget to push their font files to `bootstrap/fonts/` as well).
3. Open `bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less` for editing. You are looking for the early import declarations:

   ```
   ...
   @import "glyphicons.less";
   // Extras go here:
   @import "glyphicons-filetypes.less";
   @import "glyphicons-social.less";
   ...
   ```
4. Install `node/npm` and `grunt` if you haven't done so yet as per Bootstrap's "Getting Started" section's [instructions](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#grunt). Proceed:

   ```
   you@home:~/bs3_src$ npm install
   you@home:~/bs3_src$ grunt dist
   ```

By now your `bootstrap/dist/` folder should have a glorious set of combined `*.css`, `*.min.css` and `*.map` files with the appropriate font families, along with all of the other PRO add-on goodies. Copy it's sub-folders into your project's assets and link accordingly.

The good thing about this approach is that it can be automated as a workflow (check this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040766/replacing-the-standard-glyphicons-halflings-with-glyphicons-pro-in-bootstrap-3)) to incorporate periodic updates from Bootstrap or Glyphicons, not to mention any custom `.less` that needs to be compiled.

As far as overriding the class schemes, i.e. "glyphicons glyphicons-ok" => "gi gi-ok": Any regex or `repl` type operation on the source less files before compiling would quickly achieve this. You'll simply have to be vigilant to make sure any of your other third-party apps aren't affected adversely.