# How to use glyphicons pro within an angular 1.6 / Bootsrap 3 project

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I've bought **Glyphicons Pro** and I'd like to use it in my **Angular 1.6.x/bootstrap 3** projects. (my first project). I've used Yeoman (yo gulp-angular), so I'm using Gulp as well (very basic knowledge)

I've found a post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22040766/replacing-the-standard-glyphicons-halflings-with-glyphicons-pro-in-bootstrap-3), but it seems a bit dated, since bootstrap is now using Sass, and the folder structure has changed.

There is a bootstrap example in the pro package, but there are no instructions, so I'm a bit lost, and I'm not sure what version of bootstrap it's using.

Also, I would need to include the change in gulp so that it builds up.

Has anyone figured out how to include Glyphicons pro in Bootstrap3+Angular 1.6?

(I'm also quite new at posting question here, feel free to give pieces of advice to improve my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to have a working solution for my project at least.

I've created a project on github

https://github.com/dev-mansonthomas/bootstrap3-glyphicons-pro

that explains the step by step procedure to manually modify bootstrap so that it uses the glyphicons pro (you still have to buy glyphicons pro ;)

I'll try to automate this later.

Basically, I've created a _glyphicons-pro.scss, and inject the CSS code from glyphicons pro bootstrap *css* example, using the *scss* syntax.

I've lightly tested it so far, I'll update the github project if needed.

I didn't include the light, drop, x2, x3... X6, flip, rotate css class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try these: Dont forget to add libraries:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Glyphicon Examples</h2>
      <p>Envelope icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></p>    
      <p>Envelope icon as a link:
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
        </a>
      </p>
      <p>Search icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></p>
      <p>Search icon on a button:
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>Search icon on a styled button:
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
        </button>
      </p>
      <p>Print icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></p>      
      <p>Print icon on a styled link button:
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print 
        </a>
      </p> 
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure to answer the question?

Glyphicons Pro is a superset of the shipped glyphicons from bootstrap, and CSS classes have an additional "s" at the end.